# Sending email from a fragment activity contact form

Tags: android, forms, email, fragment

I know questions like this have been asked already, but even after studying several other people's problems I still can't get my code to work, mostly because differences between projects have made it difficult for me to understand what and how to do.

Usually this would work, but the form is in a fragment activity so naturally I've run against several problems (some I've solved, others not), that happen because fragments don't extend this or that etc.

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View fragment1View=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
    return fragment1View;

}

public void sendEmail(View button){
    final EditText formName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.formName);
    String clientName=formName.getText().toString();
    final EditText formEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.formEmail);
    String clientEmail=formEmail.getText().toString();
    final EditText formDetails=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.formDetails);
    String clientDetails=formDetails.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"example@email.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "New Private Service Request");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TODO: compose message body");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email with...?"));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(Fragment1.this.getActivity(), "No email clients installed on device!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Basically what happens is that the findViewById for the EditText controls are all underlined as errors: "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Fragment1".
I have tried this:

```
final EditText formName=(EditText)fragment1View.findViewById(R.id.formName);
```

And though this supposedly helped some people, for me the fragment1View is simply unresolved, even though I have declared it in the onCreateView.

I've tried alot of things and just don't know what to do. I wanted to give up and go with a standard Activity instead of Fragment, but it has to be fragment. Please help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create fields for every view you want to find in your fragment. THen in `onCreateView` write something like this:

```
    Button button;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View fragment1View=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        button = (Button) fragment1View.findViewById(R.id.button);
        return fragment1View;
    }
```

You can't use `findVIewById` in fragment. But you can use it with inflated `View` in onCreateView which is actually is your fragment's layout.

Comment: So when dealing with fragment activites, I have to first declare my views as global variables, and then create fields for each one in the onCreate method? Does that mean that, in my sendEmail() method, I can with no trouble collect values from the views and then process them (String clientName=formName.getText().toString();), without additionally calling the views?

And thank you! :)

Comment: You can also not create a new field for each view but keep a reference to the fragment view you were inflating in onCreateView method and then find the appropriate view in it's view hierarchy when you need.

Comment: Meh, that second explanation is sort of abstract for me without an example (I'm still a rookie), but important thing is that your answer has done it for me. The application works properly. Thanks alot mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is while defining and initializing edittext define view with it.
for example:

final EditText formName=(EditText)**fragment1View**.findViewById(R.id.formName);

do this whenever u initialize buttons in fragment. :) 
happy coding.